# Can't build .jar file with firebase-admin-java

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, jar, firebase-admin

[This bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/845) prevents to use firebase-admin in pure Java/Kotlin projects. Is there a known fix/ad-hoc?

> The error happens after running the .jar:
>
> ```
> Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt
> ```
>
> It looks like the problem appears because of firebase:
>
> ```
> implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.2.0")
> ```
>
> Adding it in an empty project provides this error while all is ok
> without this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Seems ok after updating Java from 17 to 19 and add

```
    exclude("META-INF/*.SF")
    exclude("META-INF/*.DSA")
    exclude("META-INF/*.RSA")
```